# Why is this logical operator not working?

Tags: javascript, logical-operators

[image: shrimpcook01 css-top value]

im using the code

```
setInterval(function() {
  if (document.querySelector("#shrimpCook01").style.top > "400px") {
    alert("789")
  }
}, 200);
```

to check where shrimpcook01 is, but im receiving an alert message even though the div's top value is less than 400px.

Comment: You can't do math with a string. "400px" is not a number

Comment: do you know why I was able to receive an alert message at all if I was comparing strings versus integers(repl.it/repls/AwkwardSpiritedDeprecatedsoftware#index.php)? Also why when changing css values with javascript you write equal to strings, stackoverflow.com/questions/2214387/…, but not in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can transform your string values easily.

```js
setInterval(function() {
  const height = document.querySelector("#shrimpCook01").style.top.split('px')[0];
  if (Number(height) > 400) {
    alert("789")
  }
}, 200);
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be doing lexicographical comparison of strings.
Use parseInt to convert the value to number, and compare it against 400 number, not "400px" string.

Comment: But the screenshot says it's 275px. The comparison should work in this case.